# Fix auto-generating scss type definitions (style.d.ts) Preact webpack TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, preact

Using webpack with Preact 10.x (nearly-identical to React) and TypeScript, in VSCode.

After updating Node from version 12 to version 14 *(which may(?) be the cause of the problem)*, `*.scss` files no longer auto-generate their individual type definition files.

Previously, when I ran `webpack --mode development -w`, any new/changed `style.scss` files would automatically generate/regenerate their associated `style.d.ts` files.  This no longer happens, and I receive the error message

```
TS2307: Cannot find module style.scss or its corresponding type declarations.
```

**If I manually create (or update) the `style.d.ts` file, everything works.**

How can I fix auto-generating/auto-regenerating the `.scss` types declaration files again?

After upgrading node, I did perform the following further updates:

```
1. Terminal>  npm cache clean --force

2. Deleted the node_modules folder in the project

3. Deleted the package-lock.json file

4. Edited the tsconfig.json file and added "baseUrl": ".",  -- e.g.
   "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "etc etc etc": "etc etc etc",

5. Terminal>  npm install
```

##### My package.json:

```
    {
      "name": "myproject",
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "description": "myproject",
      "main": "backend/server.js",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "nodemon -r dotenv/config backend/server.js",
        "dev": "webpack --mode development -w --declaration",
        "build": "webpack --mode production"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "knex": "^0.21.0",
        "log4js": "^6.3.0",
        "mysql": "^2.18.1",
        "preact": "10.4.8",
        "pug": "^3.0.2"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@teamsupercell/typings-for-css-modules-loader": "^2.1.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.30.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.30.0",
        "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
        "css-loader": "^3.5.3",
        "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
        "eslint": "^6.8.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.19.0",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.9.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.3",
        "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.3",
        "prettier": "^2.0.5",
        "prettier-eslint": "^9.0.1",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
        "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
        "terser": "^4.6.13",
        "terser-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.6",
        "ts-loader": "^7.0.2",
        "tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
        "typescript": "^3.8.3",
        "webpack": "^4.43.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
      }
    }
```

##### My tsconfig.json:

```
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "target": "es2017",
        "lib": ["dom", "esnext", "esnext.array"],
        "types": ["node"],
        "module": "esnext",
        "declaration": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "strict": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "jsxFactory": "h"
      },
      "include": ["./frontend/**/*.tsx", "./frontend/**/*.ts"]
    }
```

##### My webpack.config.js:

```
    /* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/camelcase */
    /* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
    const path = require('path');
    const webpack = require('webpack');
    const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
    const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
    const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
    const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
    const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');
    const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

    module.exports = (env, argv) => {
      const compressArgs = argv.mode === 'production' ? { drop_console: true } : false;
      const mode = argv.mode === 'production' ? 'bundle' : 'dev';
      const cssNamespacing = mode === 'dev' ? '[path][local]' : '[folder][hash]';
      const chunkName = mode === 'dev' ? `[name].${mode}` : '[chunkhash]';
      const cssChunkName = mode === 'dev' ? `[name].${mode}` : '[contenthash]';
      const cleanPatterns = mode === 'dev' ? ['dev.*'] : ['**/*', '!dev.*'];
      return {
        entry: `${__dirname}/frontend/index.tsx`,
        output: {
          filename: `${mode}.[contenthash].js`,
          chunkFilename: `${chunkName}.js`,
          publicPath: '/static/app',
          path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public/app'),
        },
        plugins: [
          new CleanWebpackPlugin({
            cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns: cleanPatterns,
          }),
          new webpack.WatchIgnorePlugin([/\.d\.ts$/]),
          new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            ignoreOrder: true,
            filename: `${mode}.[contenthash].css`,
            chunkFilename: `${cssChunkName}.css`,
          }),
          new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({
            assetNameRegExp: /.(sc|c)ss$/g,
          }),
          new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'template.html',
            filename: mode === 'dev' ? 'dev.index.html' : 'index.html',
          }),
        ],
        resolve: {
          extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.css', '.scss'],
          plugins: [
            new TsconfigPathsPlugin({
              configFile: path.resolve(__dirname, 'tsconfig.json'),
            }),
          ],
        },
        module: {
          rules: [
            {
              test: /\.(sc|c)ss$/,
              use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                '@teamsupercell/typings-for-css-modules-loader',
                {
                  loader: 'css-loader',
                  options: {
                    modules: {
                      localIdentName: cssNamespacing,
                    },
                    localsConvention: 'camelCase',
                  },
                },
                'sass-loader',
              ],
            },
            {
              test: /\.tsx?$/,
              loader: 'ts-loader',
            },
          ],
        },
        optimization: {
          minimizer: [
            new TerserPlugin({
              terserOptions: {
                ecma: 8,
                warnings: false,
                compress: compressArgs,
                mangle: mode !== 'dev',
                module: false,
                keep_classnames: mode === 'dev',
                keep_fnames: mode === 'dev',
              },
            }),
          ],
          splitChunks: {
            maxSize: 200000,
            hidePathInfo: true,
            cacheGroups: {
              vendors: {
                reuseExistingChunk: true,
              },
            },
          },
        },
        stats: { children: false },
        devtool: argv.mode === 'production' ? 'source-map' : 'inline-source-map',
      };
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered some compatibility issues with `node-sass` when upgrading from node version 12 to any mayor version of node newer that version 12.
The issue (in my case) seems to be related to the `node-gyp` dependency, used internally by `node-sass` that breaks with mayor node versions higher than version 12.

The only solution I found so far is to install node version manager, and keep several node versions installed in my computer, and when need to work in projects using that dependency just switch to version 12.

Check this link to node version manager for Linux or Mac https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm, and this one for Windows https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows which is the one I'm currently using.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered something similar in my React project and the problem was that I wasn't actually using the component that was importing the styles. Once I used the component, the declaration file auto-generated.